# Gaussian fit in Python - parameters estimation

Tags: python, parameters, curve-fitting, gaussian, data-fitting

I want to fit an array of data (in the program called "data", of size "n") with a Gaussian function and I want to get the estimations for the parameters of the curve, namely the mean and the sigma. Is the following code, which I found on the Web, a fast way to do that? If so, how can I actually get the estimated values of the parameters?

```
import pylab as plb
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import asarray as ar,exp

x = ar(range(n))
y = data

n = len(x)                          #the number of data
mean = sum(x*y)/n                   #note this correction
sigma = sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n        #note this correction

def gaus(x,a,x0,sigma,c):
    return a*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(sigma**2))+c

popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus,x,y,p0=[1,mean,sigma,0.0])

print popt
print pcov

plt.plot(x,y,'b+:',label='data')
plt.plot(x,gaus(x,*popt),'ro:',label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Fig. 3 - Fit')
plt.xlabel('q')
plt.ylabel('data')
plt.show()
```

Comment: In the bottom of this IPython notebook, I show an example using `astropy`, which in turn use `scipy`.
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/j-faria/python-for-astronomers/blob/master/notebooks/Class%203%20-%20astropy.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, **"Is the following code, which I found on the Web, a fast way to do that?"**

The code that you have is in fact the right way to proceed with fitting your data, when you believe is Gaussian and know the fitting function (except change the `return` function to

`a*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(sigma**2))`.

I believe for a Gaussian function you don't need the constant `c` parameter.

A common use of least-squares minimization is curve fitting, where one has a parametrized model function meant to explain some phenomena and wants to adjust the numerical values for the model to most closely match some data. With scipy, such problems are commonly solved with [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

To answer your second question, **"If so, how can I actually get the estimated values of the parameters?"**

You can go to the link provided for `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` and find that the best fit parameters reside in your `popt` variable. In your example, `popt` will contain the `mean` and `sigma` of your data. In addition to the best fit parameters, `pcov` will contain the covariance matrix, which will have the errors of your `mean` and `sigma`. To obtain 1sigma standard deviations, you can simply use `np.sqrt(pcov)` and obtain the same.